# How to change gamma and contrast through pi

Tags: video

I want to watch the movie. I use omxplayer and computer monitor. Is it possible to change gamma and contrast?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds hard to believe but maybe omxplayer does not offer such a feature. User Deltabeard has put it this way on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/68qjj7/omxplayer_settings/):

> You can change the colour settings of your TV. Looking at the [omxplayer project page](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer), it doesn't seem to have brightness controls. Maybe use mpv instead as that has brightness, contrast controls amongst many other features.

You could use `xrandr` or `xgamma` as configuration utilities of the X-server itself (well if using omxplayer with X-server).

Comment: `DISPLAY=:0 xgamma -rgamma 1.23 -bgamma 2.34 -ggamma 3.45`